# Crash when loadingNibNamed in for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, loadnibnamed

This is in continuation to the following question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673003/crash-on-multiple-calls-to-loadnibnamed

Basically i am calling

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YFCalendarDayCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

OR

```
NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName
                                                     owner:nil
                                                   options:nil];
```

in a for loop. This eventually crashes with `BadExcess error` OR `NSArray` that is returned has zero elements.

Is there a correct way to do this?

After Adding `@Autoreleasepool`

```
int i, j, k=0;
for( i=0; i<5; i++ )
{
    for( j=0; j<7; j++ )
    {
        @autoreleasepool {
        YFCalendarDayCell *tableView = [Utility loadNibNamed:@"YFCalendarDayCell" ofClass:[YFCalendarDayCell class]];

        tableView.cellTableView.dataSource = tableView;
        tableView.cellTableView.delegate = tableView;
        tableView.controller = mainViewController;

        //[calendarView addSubview:tableView];

        NSLog(@"tables added to calendar view i: %d j: %d",i,j);

        [calendarView.CellDict setObject:tableView forKey:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:k++] stringValue]];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you face error in first line or second line of code?

Comment: Try wrapping the loop body in `@autoreleasepool { }`. Maybe you're running out of memory.

Comment: @user3182143, BadExcess for first and 0 objects for 2nd. These are two different ways i tried to load the xib.

Comment: Did you try with auto release pool inside the for loop?

Comment: trying. gimme a minute

Comment: @user3182143, i tried using for loop. It given 1 object in the NSArray and crashes with BadExcess. Editing my question with For Loop. Please check.

Comment: Post the source for `YFCalendarDayCell`. There's probably something in there that's causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below answer

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
      @autoreleasepool
      {
          for (j=0; j<7; j++)
          {

            YFCalendarDayCell *tableView = [Utility loadNibNamed:@"YFCalendarDayCell" ofClass:[YFCalendarDayCell class]];

            tableView.cellTableView.dataSource = tableView;
            tableView.cellTableView.delegate = tableView;
            tableView.controller = mainViewController;
            NSLog(@"tables added to calendar view i: %d j: %d",i,j);
            [calendarView.CellDict setObject:tableView forKey:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:k++] stringValue]];
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: Tried. Got this error `malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=1048576) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region securely`. After multiple calls.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755508/xcode-7-ios-9-iphone-4s-iphone5-only-issue-malloc-mach-vm-mapsize

Comment: Also please check with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477236/malloc-error-cant-allocate-region-failed-with-error-code-12-any-idea-how-to

Comment: Thanks. I will accept your answer because it did resolve the issue to some extent. Thanks again.

Comment: this block is in a class which is a subclass of `NSOperationQueue`. So i cannot actually use `@autoreleasepool` inside that. Any other ways of doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086913/objective-c-why-is-autorelease-autoreleasepool-still-needed-with-arc

Comment: Also this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198477/ios-autorelease-pool-blocks

Comment: actually, loading of the nib is causing the problem when done in NSOperation. Maybe the two are going out of sync. Could you please help me with this.

Comment: or maybe one is release before the latter is loaded. Is there a way to wait for nib loading inside the nsoperation

Comment: From above link and others sources say loading multiple nib in auto release pool is better.If you go through that you can get idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569244/nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue-working-thread-vs-main-thread